# Invertible matrices with eigenvalues

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ invertible matrix with eigenvalue $\lambda$ . Prove that $\lambda \ne 0$, and
prove that $A−1$ has $λ −1$ as an eigenvalue.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?  What have you tried?

Comment: Use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of copying and pasting math symbols.

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: If all else fails, give a simple example, perhaps a $2\times 2$ matrix, to illustrate your claims.  That step alone might push you into grasping the proof of one half or the other of your claims.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: what does $A v = \lambda v$ tell you when $\lambda = 0$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:** Note that for a vector $x \in \Bbb R^n$ (or $\Bbb C^n$)

- If $A$ is invertible, then $Ax = 0 \implies x = 0$
- $(A - 1)x = Ax - x$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1:** What does the phrase "$0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$" *mean*?

**Hint 2:** If by $A-1$ you mean $A-1I$, what might $(A-1I)-\lambda I$ possibly be?